# Nestjs typeorm column in child that have the value of a parent column

Tags: nestjs, typeorm, nestjs-typeorm

I have two relations, one parent and one child.

```js
@Entity()
export class Parent{
  @PrimaryGeneratedColumn('uuid')
  id: string;

  @Column()
  description: string;

  @OneToMany(() => Child, (animal) => child.parent, {
    cascade: true,
  })
  children: Child[];
}
```

```js
@Entity()
export class Child {
  @PrimaryGeneratedColumn('uuid')
  id: string;

  @Column()
  parent_description: string;

  @ManyToOne(() => Parent, (parent) => parent.children, { eager: true })
  parent: Parent;

}
```

In the child I also have a `description` of the parent, that is different for each child, so it can't be inside the `Parent`.

My problem is that when I get the `Parent` everything is good, but when I get the list of `Child` directly the `parent_description` is the same value as the `Parent` column named `description`

```js
Parent {
  id: 'cdf8d726-6c86-4dfc-85b9-ebb7bae68d68',
  description: 'Parent description',
  children: [
    Child {
      id: '0da2b990-297b-4d30-a255-86a7e5ba632a',
      parent_description: 'Child description',
    },
  ]
}
```

```js
Child{
    id: '9362ae33-9212-4d69-91f1-021dca826243',
    parent_description: 'Parent description',
  }
```

Here is the service that I use

```js
@Injectable()
export class ChildService {
  constructor(
    @InjectRepository(Child)
    private childRepository: Repository<Child>,
    @InjectRepository(Parent)
    private parentsRepository: Repository<Parent>,
  ) {}

  findOne(id: string): Promise<Child> {
    return this.childRepository.findOne({
      where: { id: id },
    });
  }
  findParent(id: string): Promise<Parent> {
    return this.parentsRepository.findOne({
      relations: ['children'],
      where: { id: id },
    });
  }
}
```

**Is it an intended behaviour ? Is it possible to disable it ?**

Comment: you mean want to change the key name?

Comment: No, I would like to keep the properties name, but have the correct data.

Comment: can you provide your querybuilder?

Comment: I use the `InjectRepository` of `@nestjs/typeorm`, I edited the post to add my service